# About xcode assets catalog and app size

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipa

I'm wondering if having images for all kind of devices in the assets catalog will make the app bundle size larger on the user's end. 
Is the ipa file downloaded with all images in the assets catalog, or just with those specific to the device the app is being downloaded to?

Answer (score 2):

As from iOS 9 and later, only those assets are downloaded with the app which are compatible with the device.

It is mentioned in this link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

> Sliced apps are supported on devices running 9.0 and later; otherwise,
>   the store delivers universal apps to customers.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a feature called "App thinning" which is designed to combat this. Basically unused assets are stripped out based on device configuration.

> The store will create and deliver different variants based on the
>   devices your app supports. Image resources are sliced according to
>   their resolution and device family. GPU resources are sliced according
>   to device capabilities.

[Apple's App Thinning Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)